# "si", "aussi", or "tellement" for "so"

Tags: choix-de-mot, adverbes

> Thanks for being so kind to me!
>
> I didn't think that it would be so hot.

Should "so" in these sentences be translated with *si*, *aussi*, or *tellement*, or does more than one work? If more than one works, do they carry different connotations?

> Merci d'être (si/aussi/tellement) gentil avec moi !
>
> Je n'ai pas pensé qu'il ferait (si/aussi/tellement) chaud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first sentence you can either use "si" or "aussi".

> Merci d'être si gentil avec moi / Merci d'être aussi gentil avec moi.

Using "si" will sound more polite, you can use "tellement" too but it won't sound natural !

For the second one it's the same, you can use both but "si" will sound more polite. You can't use "tellement" here.

Comment: I would also add "Tellement" is really different from "si" and "aussi". With "tellement" you have to be able to add "que ..." after it: "il fait tellement chaud que je vais enlever mon pull", which you can't do in a sentence like the suggested one...